# How to intercept callback on fs.createWriteStream in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger a function when this line of code is completed:

```
fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path)
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname+'/public/tmp/'+req.files.file.name));
```

I think I must be very dense, but is it correct that none of these fs functions carry a callback? How to copy `req.files.file.path` to the destination folder and intercept the completion?

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those functions do not take callbacks because they synchronously return an object that emits events. In this case, you would listen to `'finish'` on the `WriteStream` to know the copy is done. You'll also want to listen for errors:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var copy = function(from, to, callback){
    var cleanup = function(){
        dest.removeListener('finish', finish);
        dest.removeListener('error', error);
        src.removeListener('error', error);
    };
    var finish = function(){
        cleanup();
        callback(null);
    };
    var error = function(err){
        cleanup();
        callback(err);
    };

    var src = fs.createReadStream(from);
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream(to);

    dest.addListener('finish', finish);
    dest.addListener('error', error);
    src.addListener('error', error);

    src.pipe(dest);
};
```

That said, you'll probably want to just use a module rather than writing this yourself, probably something like [`fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra).